# Light and Proximity Sensors

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximitysensor, light-sensor

This question is not exactly about code but rather knowing the sensors on android phones.

My application use sensors. So I would like to know is Light sensor or Proximity sensor is present on most of Devices. I have got some test devices and my observation is only higher end devices have got Light Sensor whereas the same is not available on lower end(low cost) Phones but the Proximity is available on all Phones. There would be someone playing with sensors so far, can share your observation so I can take the decision what to choose to go further with my application.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html
and especially the "Sensor Availability" part.

My personal observation is that proximity and light sensors are available at least from 19 and work so far on Samsung, ASUS, Huawei, and other devices. But light sensors are more sensitive on high-end devices. So sometimes an extreme light change is needed for a light sensor on lower-end devices to even show a change from baseline 0.0. Proximity sensors work more reliably across versions, but the distance they support varies from 5cm until 10cm and more.

In short these sensors will work virtually on all relevant devices, but their sensitivity itself will be different.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.You mean sensor availability is dependent or Android versions? Actually my app targets api 21 and above. As mentioned earlier I have got some phones for testing. As we can detect the sensor presence on run time on one  device running on 7.0 AV Light sensor is not present.

Comment: Maybe the light sensor is broken or the manufacturer decided to save costs by not integrating it. If lower end devices are important then yes, it becomes more fragmented.

Comment: okay. As of your observation, most devices running at least from 19 will have Light sensor except some exceptional devices?

Comment: Some 1-5% I guess will be an exception(from low-end devices), so some fallback has to be in place anyway.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge Demonick:)